# How to strip non-numeric characters from BigQuery results

Tags: google-bigquery, strip

I've seen information on how to [add commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359504/format-a-number-to-have-commas-1000000-1-000-000) to a number in BigQuery, but I am getting dollar amount results

```
$15,000
$25,000
$10,000
```

that I would like to convert into pure numbers

```
15000
25000
10000
```

I haven't found any BigQuery function for a format change like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

many different ways - for example below one uses regular expression to remove `$` and `,` chars

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '$15,000' AS dollar_amount UNION ALL
  SELECT '$25,000' UNION ALL
  SELECT '$10,000' 
)
SELECT 
  dollar_amount, 
  CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(dollar_amount, r'\$|,', '') as INT64) amount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Another idea would be to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` with `[0-9]+`, then `ARRAY_TO_STRING` to concatenate the output as a more generic solution in case there are other extraneous characters.

Comment: or just `CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(dollar_amount, r'[^0-9.]', '') AS INT64)` to avoid extra ARRAY related stuff

Comment: This is great. For some reason it wasn't recognizing any ```INT``` types I wanted to cast to, but even doing the ```REGEXP_REPLACE()``` on its own works perfectly. It'll get read in as a number anyway when I pass the data along.

Comment: if you are using `INT` - you should use 'INT64'. At the same time - if your amounts have decinals  - you should use `FLOAT64` instead `INT64`